# Javascript function that uses result and passes it as new argument

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, arguments

I want to write a function using Javascript that returns results from a series of calculations back in the console. The function when ran, takes in a number ***N*** and does some math on it, then takes the result and passes it into the same function to produce another result, then takes that result and does the same thing, and repeats until it reaches 1 or 0. Basically, it takes an initial number, ***N***, produces an answer, then takes that answer and uses it as the new ***N***, and this repeats until ***N*** === 1 || 0.

Currently, I'm only getting the first result and that being printed ***N*** number of times.

```
N = 350;

Current output:
50
50
50
50
50
50
... 344 items left

Expected output:

50
7
1
```

How can I take the result, 50, and pass it as the new argument for ***N*** and repeat this?

Function:

```
let N = 350;

function compute(N) {
  for (var i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    let rS = N / 3.5;
    let result = rS / 2;
    let rounded = Math.round(result);

    if (rounded === 1 || 0) {
      console.log(rounded);
    } else {
      console.log(`N = ${result}`)
    }
  }
  return null;
}

return factor(N);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rs = N / 3.5;
let result = rS / 2; // Doing this is exactly the same as dividing by 7 since the `rS` variable isn't used anywhere else in the function
```

`rounded === 1 || 0` // This condition makes no sense because if  `rounded === 1` fails, the other 0 will still equal 0 instead you should use `rounded >= 0 && rounded < 2` or `rounded == 1 || rounded == 0`

I also don't see use of the `for` loop, when you don't use the value of the `i` variable

You can use the result as a new argument for the function. By calling the function again with the result. Functions like that are called recursive functions.

```js
let N = 350;

function compute(N) {
    const result = N / 7;
    const rounded = Math.floor(result);
    
    console.log(rounded);
    if (rounded >= 0 && rounded < 2) return rounded;
    else compute(result);
}

compute(N);
```